# Why does the unit name 'mb' correspond to 'millibarns', not 'millibars'?

Tags: metpy

millibarns is a unit of cross-section for collisions
in particle physics.  MetPy caters to meteorologists,
who would normally interpret 'mb' to be millibars,
a unit of pressure.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking, but this might be better addressed to https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy

Answer (score 1):

MetPy's unit support is handled by the [pint](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/0.9/) library, which dictates what can be used. According to the [wikipedia article on the bar unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_(unit)), the use of the "b" abbreviation for bar is deprecated due to the confusion with barne.